# Trying to remove background and make it transparent in c++, using magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I am having an image "objects.png" with a red background and I'm trying to make the background transparent. The code is straight forward but somehow I am not able to get the desired result. I am quite new to this ImageMagick business and this is my first program using Magick++. So, it would be great if you can explain things in detail. Thanks in advance. Code goes like this,

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Magick++.h>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace Magick;

    int main(){
        Image my_image("objects.png");
        Color bg_color = my_image.pixelColor(0,0);
        Color new_bg_color(0, MaxRGB, 0, MaxRGB);

        for (int i=0;i<my_image.columns();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<my_image.rows();j++){
                //cout<<"(i,j) : ("<<i<<","<<j<<")\n";
                if (my_image.pixelColor(i,j) == bg_color){
                    my_image.pixelColor(i,j,new_bg_color);
                }
            }
        }
        my_image.write("new_objects.png"); 
    }
```

Image objects.png is
[image: input image]

and I'm getting this as output 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a `Magick::Image.transparent` method that should handle transparency assignment.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(){
    Image my_image("objects.png");
    Color bg_color = my_image.pixelColor(0,0);
    my_image.transparent(bg_color);
    my_image.write("new_objects.png"); 
}
```

**Edit**

To allow the `Magick::Color`'s opacity to be respected. You need to enable the alpha channel of the image by setting `Magick::Image.matte`, or `Magick::Image.opacity` attributes.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(){
    Image my_image("objects.png");
    Color bg_color = my_image.pixelColor(0,0);
    Color new_bg_color(0, MaxRGB, 0, MaxRGB);

    my_image.matte(true); // or my_image.opacity();
    for (int i=0;i<my_image.columns();i++){
        for (int j=0;j<my_image.rows();j++){
            if (my_image.pixelColor(i,j) == bg_color){
                my_image.pixelColor(i,j,new_bg_color);
            }
        }
    }
    my_image.write("new_objects.png"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @emcconville 
But can you please explain what is wrong with my code, why it is not giving desired results?

Comment: Actually I am not trying to remove background here. I am trying to do something else which also uses the same logic. Can you please through some light on my piece of code?

Comment: @ABCoder Your code is fine, but the alpha channel is ignored. This approach will work, but will be slow. Take a look at [Low-Level Image Pixel Access](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#Raw%20Image%20Pixel%20Access). It seems like more work, but you will have more control & will have the exact behavior your expecting.

Comment: Oh thank you very much @emcconville
See, these are the things what a starter has to face